# Re-use a random forest with R

Tags: r, random-forest

I'd like to know if it's possible to re-use the rules of a random forest, on different test set.

For now, I'm using this :

```
  rf <-randomForest(x=train,y=labels_train,xtest=test, ytest=labels_test,  ntree=1000)
  save(rf,file = "rf_.RData")
```

I know how to save the random forest, but I don't see how I can re-use the rules, for several test set.

Comment: By saving your object, you should be able to use `predict` the next time.

Comment: In addition to @RomanLuštrik's answer, you need to specify `keep.forest = TRUE` as you give `xtest`